# IronPython: how to get names from Python expression?

Tags: ironpython

I have a string with a Python expression, for example:

```
"x + y * 2 > z"
```

How to get a list of names used in the expression? In the above example the list is:

```
x, y, z
```

In Python I think I could use the parser module, but how to do it in IronPython, where the parser module seems to be unavailable?

Answer (score 2):

This page might help you: http://www.ironpython.info/index.php/The_IronPython_2_Parser

It has an example of creating an AST from a python expression using the underlying IronPython compiler and then printing the names of objects found there.

I went ahead and applied it to your problem. I'm using IronPython 2.0.1 here, just in case you are on a newer version and they changed something...

```
# run this with IronPython 2
import clr
clr.AddReference('IronPython')
clr.AddReference('Microsoft.Scripting')

from IronPython.Hosting import Python
from IronPython.Compiler import Parser
from IronPython.Compiler.Ast import PythonWalker
from IronPython.Compiler.Ast import NameExpression
from Microsoft.Scripting import ErrorSink
from Microsoft.Scripting import SymbolTable
from Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime import CompilerContext
from Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.Providers import HostingHelpers


class ExpressionWalker (PythonWalker):
    def __init__(self):
        self.names = []
    def Walk(self, node):
        if isinstance(node, NameExpression):
            self.names.append(SymbolTable.IdToString(node.Name))
        return True

py = Python.CreateEngine()
src = HostingHelpers.GetSourceUnit(py.CreateScriptSourceFromString('x + y * 2 > z'))
pylc = HostingHelpers.GetLanguageContext(py)
p = Parser.CreateParser(CompilerContext(src, pylc.GetCompilerOptions(), ErrorSink.Default), pylc.Options)
ast = p.ParseFile(True)

walker = ExpressionWalker()
ast.Walk(walker)
print walker.names
```

This prints out the following:

```
['x', 'y', 'z']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Regex class of the .NET Framework :

```
import clr

clr.AddReference('System')
from System.Text.RegularExpressions import Regex

operation = "x + y * 2 > z"

regex = Regex("[a-zA-Z]+")
matches = regex.Matches("x + y * 2 > z")
result = ""
for m in matches:
    result += m.Value + ","

print result
```

Comment: for simple problems like this one, yes, that might work. But not in a general case.

Comment: What do you mean by "in general case"? I don't understand your comment. Could you please be more explicit?

Comment: sorry for not answering earlier. By "in the general case" I mean for any possible python expression. This can include keywords (e.g. `is` or `lambda`).

Answer (score 0):

```
print filter(lambda x: x.isalpha(), list("x + y * 2 > z"))
```

## OR

```
def parse_expression(expression, operations=['+','-','*','/','%','^']):
    output = []
    tmp = None
    for x in expression:
        if x.strip() == '':
            continue
        if tmp is None:
            tmp = [x]
        elif not x in operations:
            tmp.append(x)
        else:
            output.append(''.join(tmp))
            tmp = None
    (tmp is not None and output.append(''.join(tmp)))
    return output
```

## OR

```
import re
print re.findall(r'(?i)(?:[a-z0-9_]+)', ('test_1+ y__2 * c/_3')
```

Comment: what about variables with names like `buffalo_bill`?

Comment: I have tried to check the simplest one case. In the case of complex names there would be another solution with regex or using the operator module